# Blob upload failing on azure using REST API

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have followed this tutorial exactly as it is.
[How to use the Blob service from PHP](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/how-to-guides/blob-service/)

Now this works super cool from my localhost. But same set of configs and all stops working when I deploy it to Azure.

And the worst part is, the error info I could get after enabling error report on azure is 
**HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error**
Nothing else !

Please help.!

Request Header:


**GET /index.php/api/blobtest HTTP/1.1

Host: eduora-staging.azurewebsites.net

Connection: keep-alive

Cache-Control: max-age=0

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36

Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Cookie: ARRAffinity=f5105030b49455c354a66ad349ab75b57b342f0a8b721d229021b4f0df2e5a15; 
WAWebSiteSID=3f247e6be7204ef5a21d5ff5a2248389**

Response header:


**HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Content-Length: 499

Content-Type: text/html

Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0

X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.19

DWAS-Handler-Name: PHP53_via_FastCGI

X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5

X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

Date: Mon, 21 Oct 2013 18:48:12 GMT**

I could look @ php_errors.log which says
**[21-Oct-2013 11:20:22 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Fatal error: Class 'WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder' not found.**

But this class is linked properly from localhost !

Comment: Have you used something like Fiddler to see what REST request you are sending and what is being returned?

Comment: Yeah I use Fiddler. It returns HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error as response header.

Comment: Can you add the Fiddler Request and Response data?  It is really hard to know what you are trying to do from the brief description provided.

Comment: I have updated my post have a look.

Comment: This Fiddler trace shows a call to your eduora-staging.azurewebsites.net, not to blob storage.  From this trace it shows that your index.php page is returning an HTTP 500 because class 'WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder' could not be found.  So this appears to have nothing to do with blob storage.  You may want to try modifying your question and tags to accurately reflect that this is an issue with your sited hosted in WAWS rather than an issue with blob storage.

Comment: Lol You are awesome :) 
Host: eduora-staging.azurewebsites.net just refers to the hostname being accessed during this request NOT THE URL ITSELF:)
Let me Elaborate it for you. 
I have this URL http://eduora-staging.azurewebsites.net/index.php/api/blobtest
which has functions written to access azure blob store :)
Now I had followed the tutorial and have exact same code to connect to container and all :)
But this simply does not work on azure itself :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39684/discussion-between-muhammad-riyaz-and-kwill)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to upload the contents of "vendor/microsoft/windowsazure" manually and Its working fine !
(But I dont know why It dint get pushed itself to server on my master branch)